# Access Shared Folder over internet

Tags: c#, network-programming, network-share, network-connection

i creating website using C# and i have shared folder in another network computer,
now i need to explore all files and folders inside the shared folder from my webpage using(domain or static IP - Username - Password).
i need users can access the shared folder files and download it only.

this code it's work to copy files but from network, and not working over internet:

```
NetworkCredential theNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential(@"Domain\Username", "Password");
        CredentialCache theNetCache = new CredentialCache();
        theNetCache.Add(new Uri(@"\\Domain"), "SHARED", theNetworkCredential);
        string[] theFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(@"\\Servername\SHARED\");




        string sourceDirectory = theFolders[1];
        string targetDirectory = @"E:\Shared";

        DirectoryInfo diSource = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory);
        DirectoryInfo diTarget = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);

        CopyAll(diSource, diTarget);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need create a VPN to have access in your personal network using internet, the other alternative is use a cloud storage like google drive or microsoft skydrive.

Comment: thanks for your reply. my shared folder updated everyday (new files or remove files).  so i need to access this folder.